# Inline Function with temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting crazy trying to make this function fast. I have an employee hierarchy relation between employee and manager. Here is my function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[EmployeeHierarchy] (
    @PeriodIds AS [pit].[PeriodIds] READONLY, 
    @EmployeeId int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN 
(   

    WITH relation AS 
    (
       SELECT @EmployeeId as EmployeeId, (SELECT MIN(PeriodId) FROM @PeriodIds) as PeriodId, 0 AS LEVEL

       UNION ALL

       SELECT r.EmployeeId, r.PeriodId, LEVEL + 1 AS LEVEL
         FROM (SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerId, PeriodId FROM dbo.EmployeeManagerRelation) r
        INNER JOIN relation T 
           ON r.ManagerId = T.EmployeeId
        INNER JOIN @PeriodIds P 
           ON p.PeriodId = r.PeriodId
        WHERE r.ManagerId <> r.EmployeeId 
          AND r.PeriodId = T.PeriodId

    )  

    SELECT DISTINCT  EmployeeId, LEVEL FROM relation 

)
```

If I run this outside the function it takes 0 seconds but as soon as I call the function, it takes forever. I rebuild indexes, update statistics. I also execute this commands:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

But nothing works, any idea what's the issue? If it's parameter sniffing, I don't know what to do because I can't create variables, before it wasn't an inline function and I have same issue, I don't know what to do, it's confuse because so other clients use the same but this is not consistent

This is how I call the function :

```
DECLARE @PeriodIds AS [pit].[PeriodIds]

    INSERT INTO @PeriodIds
    SELECT [PeriodId]
      FROM dbo.[Period]
     WHERE PeriodMonth = 1
       and PeriodYear = 2015

SELECT EmployeeId FROM [dbo].[EmployeeHierarchy](@PeriodIds, 322)
```

Comment: Please start by checking the execution plan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan

Comment: if I try to run the estimated execution plan, it doesn't respond. is there any way to reset the statistics or something?

Comment: How are you calling the function when it takes so much time? It could be the way you are using it(i.e. nonSARGable predicate). In addition to the execution plan the table structures including indexes would help here.

Comment: The estimated plan might help and will likely contain come useful information but the actual execution plan would be preferred (not always possible if the query takes an hour or whatever).

Comment: I added the call to the function

Comment: You could certainly try updating statistics, but I doubt that would help if the exact same query works fast when it's not called in a function.   Maybe using Recompile would help.  This article has a lot to say about parameter sniffing in TVFs:   http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options

Comment: Actually I see a lot of promising-looking articles in these results:   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=sql+server+table+valued+function+with+recompile&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=sql+server+table+valued+function+with+recompile&gs_l=hp....0.0.6.9818614...........0.jkp2fv6aXDU

Comment: I can't use recompile inside CTE I guess

Comment: what it's funny about this is that for some clients the same function works very fast and for some others no

Comment: Hopefully the Query Optimizer is smart enough to rewrite this part, but if not, change this ( `FROM (SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerId, PeriodId FROM dbo.EmployeeManagerRelation)` ) to simply be ( `FROM dbo.EmployeeManagerRelation` ). Also, Inline TVFs do not maintain their own plan since their definition is inserted into the calling query, hence no use in sticking a recompile in there. Also, why call FREEPROCCACHE twice?

Comment: I was just trying many things :)

Comment: Do you have to stick with the adjacency list model? If you converted this to nested sets you would be able to eliminate the recursion and quite possibly the entire need for a function. Here is a great article that discusses this type of conversion. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/

Comment: I can't change my code at this moment

Comment: Looks like parameter sniffing to me. Add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at the very end of your query, see what that gives.

Comment: Also this derived table is totally unnecessary: `(SELECT EmployeeId, ManagerId, PeriodId FROM dbo.EmployeeManagerRelation) r`... just start with `dbo.EmployeeManagerRelation` in your FROM clause, lose the derived table.

Comment: I can't put OPTION(RECOMPILE) inside CTE

Comment: I mean I can use it but because is an inline function I cannot

Comment: Let me quote myself: *"Add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at the very end of your query"*. Not in your CTE, at the end of the whole query. This `OPTION` is for the whole query, CTE included. An additional option to try is `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` to prevent parameter sniffing.

Comment: Also if you want to address someone in comments and want to have them alerted, put the name of the addressee with a `@` in front. Eg `@TT.` if you want to address me.

Comment: Ok @TT, let me try it

Comment: @TT, I can't add this hint inside my inline function, do you have an example of how?